# Is there a way to simply copy console output into new text file?

Tags: java, text, console, output

I had a very simple request, I have a full code that sorts through an input file and outputs the merged strings properly into the console. My question is can I take this already perfect output from my CONSOLE and simply output it into a seperate .txt fle as well?

I've tried doing a simple
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
System.setOut(printStream);

it does create my output.txt file, but it's always empty?

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1: Output via Terminal

Since your script already outputs perfectly to the terminal, you can redirect that output to a file via `>`

```
$ ./my-script > output.txt
```

You can also use the `tee` command if you still want to see the output in your terminal.

```
$ ./my-script | tee output.txt
```

## Option 2: Generate file via code

I'm not too familiar with Java / PrintStream but from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/printstream_print_string.htm, you should see content in your file by:

```
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt")); 

printStream.print("foo");

printStream.flush();
```

Comment: Right, i'd love to do that, without having to go into command prompt. Rather simple way of copying the console output from my ide (visual studio code) into a seperate output.txt